# Button to send email in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have try to add a button on user show page to send email on the address of the user mentioned in the user table.When I click on Send Invitation Email, i am running through an error **undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass**. Kindly let me know the mistake i am doing.

routes.rb

```
get 'send_invitation_email', to: 'users#invitation_confirmation'
```

invitation_confirmation.text.erb

```
Hi,

Thank you for setting up an account. Please click on the link in that email to start using the system. 

<%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
```

user_mailer.rb

```
def invitation_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "<#{user.email}>", subject: "Notification")
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def invitation_confirmation
    @user = User.find(params[:id])  
    UserMailer.invitation_confirmation(@user).deliver
    flash[:notice] = "Invitation email has been sent."
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? || current_user.superadmin? %>
   <%= link_to "Send Invitation Email", send_invitation_email_path(@user), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Update

```
mail(:to => "<#{user.email}>", subject: "Notification")
```

Comment: The error should also specify which file and line the error is occurring on. Could you add that information to your question?

Comment: From the code you provided, it looks like `user` is `nil` inside your mailer, which is being passed from controller action `invitation_confirmation`. So, `User.find(params[:id])` must be returning `nil`. Can you share the output of `rake routes` and also the server logs for the request?

Comment: please share the rake routes and also the log of request which you're sending.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that user is nil inside of your UserMailer.invitation_confirmation method.

Try:

```
def invitation_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => "<#{@user.email}>", subject: "Notification")
end
```

Comment: The error `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass.` suggests that `user` is `nil` in mailer. If you are assigning `user` to `@user`, then `@user` will also be `nil`. This doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def invitation_confirmation(user)
  mail(to: user.email, subject: "Notification")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code of show.html.erb to this if @user object is not being null:

```
<% if logged_in? && current_user.admin? || current_user.superadmin? %>
  <%= link_to "Send Invitation Email", send_invitation_email_path(id: @user.id), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def invitation_confirmation
    @user = User.find(params[:format]) 
    **@user.create_reset_digest**   
    UserMailer.invitation_confirmation(@user).deliver
    flash[:notice] = "Invitation email has been sent."
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

I was doing a mistake in the line in bold. I have not created_reset_digest. It is working now. Thankyou all.